# Bootstrap utilities

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

So I want to user Bootstrap 4.6 in my react app.
Based on this [blog post](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-bootstrap-with-react-a354715d1121/) I decided to add the link to the CDN (I don't want to use react bootstrap)
So I edited my template like this :

in the  I added

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

And juste before closing the body I added

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```
<!--public/index.html-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta name="description" content="TS webapp" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="logo192.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Echino Portal</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm able to use what I will call "basic bootstrap" (row, col, ...) but the utilities don't work. For example if I want to add a margin top to a row I should be able to do like this :

```
<div class="row mt-15">...</div>
```

But there is no margin applied. What am I missing to have the utilities of bootstrap working?

Thanks

Comment: mt-15 is not gonna work they set margin and padding from 0 to 5 you can't use bigger number than that you should use mt-5 kindly read this docs
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/spacing/

Comment: Thanks a lot man, it was that. I'm such an idiot T_T

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @muhaymin khan there is the answer :

mt-15 is not gonna work they set margin and padding from 0 to 5 you can't use bigger number than that you should use mt-5 kindly read this docs getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/spacing

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple and working way of adding the bootstrap is by doing the following,

**Step 1:** npm install --save-dev bootstrap popper.js jquery

**Step 2:** add the path file 'bootstrap.min.css' in the index.js/App.js after the import path file of 'react' and 'react-dom'.

*That's it. It will work like charm!*

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that I see wrong is that you use **class** same as in HTML, class word in react is replaced with className

```js
<div className="row mt-15">...</div>
```

It should give you an error if you use just **class**

I am not familiar with this version of bootstrap but in the source code there is no class for `mt-15`
I saw here https://www.jquery-az.com/bootstrap-margin-padding-classes-spacing-explained-5-examples/
that you can use
`mt-sm-3` and `mb-sm-3` for top and bottom margin.

You can set margin also with `style` attribute in react
e.g.

```
style={{ marginBottom: 25 }}
```

It is shown on the link that you have posted.

Also I can advice you to use everything as module from npm, you can try the second part from the tutorial that you have posted

```
npm install bootstrap
```